# App Engine returns error when used with User Services

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-userservice

I was trying to interate User Service to my App to restrict access. The app worked fine while in eclipse but once I deployed it to app engine it does not redirect to Google Login page as expected but comes with Error: 
**Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.**
This is a section of the servlet used:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

public class MyLogin  extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();

    String thisURL = "/home.html";

    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    if (req.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
        resp.getWriter().println("<p>Hello, " +
                                 req.getUserPrincipal().getName() +
                                 "!  You can <a href=\"" +
                                 userService.createLogoutURL(thisURL) +
                                 "\">sign out</a>.</p>");
    } else {
        resp.getWriter().println("<p>Please <a href=\"" +
                                 userService.createLoginURL(thisURL) +
                                 "\">sign in</a>.</p>");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you look at the App Engine logs in the console and check the error log. It will give you more details on what has gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually did and it keeps pointing me to the file above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by moving the files I intend to protect out of the root directory.